# Tile/Paver interlocked design patterns -dimensions do not add -what am I missing?

Tags: tile, design

Take this pattern for example, the three pieces circled there won't align at the edges if you want to maintain the same gap between the tiles/pavers.
For he horizontal 6x12 the width is 12 +2x1/4 gaps at each end =12.5"
The two pieces below it have three gaps there so the width is 6+6+3x1/4=12.75"

What am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: Are the tile exact 6x12 or nominal size like a 2x4 stud?  Bet the tile size takes the gaps in mind.

Comment: found the design pattern here https://digitalassets.daltile.com/content/dam/Daltile/website/resources/products/pattern-guides/interlocked.pdf

Comment: It looks like they use nominal sizes(as with most construction material).  The actual tile size is probably closer to 5 7/8(1/8 plus 1/8 equals 1/4 inch gap) than 6 inch.

Comment: even if it is I do not see that difference disappearing and it amplifies as you go east west in the picture. I mean the 12" wide tile is not 12" either so ...the same problem different dimensions

Comment: I am just going by guessing here and to be sure would have to measure the tiles, but imagine the tiles are sized so that pattern works to give straight lines.  Just because a label says 6x12 does not mean it will measure 6x12, might be 5 7/8 x 12 1/8(whatever).  Imagine if you go to that site, they might have a page with actual sizes.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

The blocks include an allowance for the seams.

[image]

Comment: Please re draw the above for the tiles that I encircled, geometrically it is impossible to maintain the same grout space for all the the tiles

Comment: the blocks are 6x6 and 12x6 when measured to the center of the grout gap

Comment: Got this reply from a tile expert: "Mini, for what is called a "modular" layout (what you have depicted there), the pattern will work only if the manufacturer has sized the tiles for such a layout. And there is only one grout joint size that will work.

The tiles must be sized such that two short sides + one grout joint equals one long side. If your tiles won't permit that, your layout is not gonna work. And whatever grout joint it takes to make that true is the only grout joint you can use with the entire layout.
"

Comment: In other words that won't work with just any tiles

Comment: @MiniMe it doesn't work if the tiles are exactly 6 or 12 inches.  They aren't. Unless you have them in your hand and measured them, expect them to work if the manufacturer is telling you they do.